# Creating buckets in apache spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I want to store data in spark such that the timestamps with difference of 5 seconds or less fall into one 5 seconds bucket along with the corresponding data. Likewise, the next set of 5 seconds bucket with the remaining logs. (So that I can aggregate data in the buckets). My logs:

```
1472120400.107 HTTP GEO er.aujf.csdh.jkhydf.eyrgt
1472120399.999 HTTP GEO er.asdhff.cdn.qyirg.sdgsg
1472120397.633 HTTP GEO er.abff.kagsf.weyfh.ajfg
1472120397.261 HTTP GEO er.laffg.ayhrff.agyfr.yawr
1472120394.328 HTTP GEO er.qfryf.aqwruf.oiuqwr.agsf
1472120393.737 HTTP GEO er.aysf.aouf.ujaf.casf
.
.
.
```

I still can't figure out how to do it in spark.

The logs with timestamps 1472120400.107,1472120399.999,1472120397.633,1472120397.261 etc fall into one bucket, the next set in the next bucket and so on.

Output:

All the loglines with timestamps 1472120400.107,1472120399.999,1472120397.633,1472120397.261 will be kept in memory (one bucket) so that further processing will be done to those like finding the count for the entire bucket. Similarly, the next bucket.

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: what do you mean by "buckets" ?

Comment: That is nothing but partitioning the logs. The partitioned group of logs form the bucket.

Answer (score 0):

Just divide the timestamp by the granularity you want to create. Keep the bin number as key in PairRDD where data is the input and then reduceByKey.

I will write code example in Scala, basically turning it to python is trivial I want to make the point.

```
val l5 = List("1472120400.107 HTTP GEO er.aujf.csdh.jkhydf.eyrgt", "1472120399.999 HTTP GEO er.asdhff.cdn.qyirg.sdgsg") 
val l5RDD = sc.parallelize(l5) //input as RDD
val l5tmp = l5RDD.map(item => item.split(" ")) //Split the sentence
val l5tmp2 = l5tmp.map(item => ((item(0).toDouble/3600000).toInt, List(item))) //Map the data to a bin (in the key) according to the wanted granularity
val collected = l5tmp2.reduceByKey(_ ++ _) //Collect the lists to create the bins of data
collected.collect().foreach(println) //Prints (408,List([Ljava.lang.String;@2c6aed22, [Ljava.lang.String;@e322ec9)) - means that both entries collected to a bin named 408
```

Comment: I didn't understand this part of the code: `val collected = l5tmp2.reduceByKey(_ ++ _)`. What's the ++?

Comment: @kaks You need to define how to collect the items together, in this case I keep the items inside lists, so in order to add the lists together I use ++. each List will hold all the items that should fall into the bin

Comment: Could you tell how we can write that in python? I'm having a tough time with that.

Comment: Can you give me a hint how I can write it in python. I tried reduceByKey(add) but shows add is not defined